# How to get rid of extraneous points outside of a closed curve using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, smoothing

I am trying to "shrink" the size of the outer boundary (in red) that is a set of pixels along the edge of an image. I already shrunk the boundary using normal vectors, and I have a set of points that are a certain distance inside the outer boundary. However, there are a lot of points that I could get rid of to make the inner boundary (in blue) smoother. So, how do I get rid of the extraneous points?

[image]

I tried converting everything to polar coordinates, and then taking the point that is closest to to the center of the image for each interval of pi/60 radians from 0 to 2pi. However, I realized that this wouldn't work for something like boomerang-ish shape, where there would be two points that I would want to keep in the pi/60 interval.

polarShrunk is the set of shrunk points converted to polar coordinates
cell_img is the object with a distanceBetween method that finds the distance between two points and a findMoments method which finds the "center of mass" of the image when it binarized to black and white. pol2cart converts polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates

```
i = 0
smoothArray = []
for x in range(120):
    i += 1
    theta1 = (i - 1)*np.pi/60
    theta2 = i*np.pi/60
    simAnglePoints = []
    for y in polarShrunk:
        if (y[0] < theta2) and (y[1] > theta1):
            simAnglePoints.append(y)
    closestPoint = np.array([10000, 10000])
    for z in np.array(simAnglePoints):
        if cell_img.distanceBetween(np.array(cell_img.pol2cart(z)), cell_img.findMoments) < cell_img.distanceBetween(closestPoint, cell_img.findMoments):
            closestPoint = z
    smoothArray.append(closestPoint)
```

I want only the points that follow the black line that I drew over the picture, and to get rid of all of the other points from the polarShrunk array.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! I really only need a way to approach this problem, and I would like to figure out how to implement that approach in Python on my own.

Comment: Seems like you want to detect and remove *outliners*. There are many articles describing different techniques to do this, e.g. [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-brief-overview-of-outlier-detection-techniques-1e0b2c19e561).